# IntelliSense: identifier "IDXGISwapChain1" is undefined

Tags: c++, graphics, nvidia, nsight

I have saved a captured frame using NVIDIA Nsight and when I open the saved solution file I get the following itellisense error:

> IntelliSense: identifier "IDXGISwapChain1" is undefined [..]

I have made no changes to the solution.

I also get the follow errors when building (using VS2013):

> Error  1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   5   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   6   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   7   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   8   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   9   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   10  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   11  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1_temp_1'    C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   88  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   12  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   88  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   13  error C2065: 'DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1_temp_1' : undeclared identifier C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   88  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   14  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC_temp_1'  C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   89  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   15  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   89  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   16  error C2065: 'DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC_temp_1' : undeclared identifier   C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   89  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   17  error C2065: 'IDXGIFactory2' : undeclared identifier    C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   90  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   18  error C2059: syntax error : ')' C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   90  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   19  error C2227: left of '->Release' must point to class/struct/union/generic type  C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   727 1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   20  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   771 1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   21  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   771 1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   22  error C2086: 'int *pIDXGISwapChain1_uidof_68' : redefinition    C:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources00.cpp   771 1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   23  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>   Error   24  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users[...]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  1   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
>       25  IntelliSense: identifier "IDXGISwapChain1" is undefined c:\Users[...]\Documents\NVIDIA Nsight\Captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h   27  8   build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15

Comment: IntelliSense sometimes says thing that aren't true.  Some would say "often".

Comment: Alright, but I also get errors when building, like:
`Error 2 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' c:\users\[..]\documents\nvidia nsight\captures\build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15\Resources.h 27 1 build11__2015_06_20__15_15_15
`

Comment: Edited my question with the build errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in the way Nsight serializes the frame. The solution is to add

```
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
```

to `resources.h`

and, in my case, change the second parameter to `CreateSwapChainForHwnd` from `NULL` to `hWindow_000D060E` in the `Resources00.cpp` file.